# C# + PHP in the same application?

Tags: c#, php, interface

What im trying to do is a little different, im wondering, if its possible to create sorts of an interface, so that if a particular function is called in php (stand alone), than the arguments will be forwarded to a method in C#, and vice versa.

Comment: Use a webservice. I'm guessing you can write soap webservices with PHP, though not sure. You definitely can for C#, and having webservices between the two is the best way for them to communicate with eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of course on what kind of data you want to exchange, if the applications are on the same server or on two different ones etc.

I did briding between PHP and C# in some of my web based projects. What I did: create an ASP.NET MVC project which exposes a RESTful API. The methods exposed by this API are then called from PHP via HTTP (using CURL). I used JSON as a data exchange format to pass data from PHP to C# and back again. This worked good as the two applications were on different servers.

I could also imagine some kind of socket server. E. g. a background process written in C# is listening on some port, and then you connect to it via PHP´s socket functions. I did something like this to connect PHP and Java. The Java app ran as a demon process on port XXXX and was a wrapper around Apache FOP. I used PHPs socket functions to pass XML and XSLT to the Java demon which then used Apache FOP to transform the data into a pdf and returned that via the socket connection back to PHP which in turn sent the PDF file to the client requesting the page.

There are probably some other approaches, but these were my experiences so far in connecting two different technologies together.

EDIT: as an aside: PHP on a windows webserver using IIS was really not that nice to work with. Sometimes strange errors occured or certain permission related errors that were not easy to resolve. YMMV though.